# Proper way for a man to go the mikvah on Friday

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

What is the proper way for a man to immerse himself in a mikvah on erev Shabbos and Erev Yomim Tovim? How many times should he completely immerse?

Comment: Hi Jon. I think that this is a wider question than you intended. If there's a particular minhag that you're asking about, that would be good to know, as it would help others respond with better info